# Ecto Reload belongs_to Association After Successful Repo.update

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Changing the association of a given `child` from `parent_a` to `parent_b` via `parent_id` in params leaves a stale `record.parent` object.

e.g. (assume params matches `%{child: %{id: '1', parent_id: '6'}}`)

```
# ...
child = Repo.get(Child, child_id)
|> preload([:parent])
changeset = Child.changeset(child, child_params)

case Repo.update(changeset) do
  {:ok, child} ->
    IO.puts child.parent_id # returns '6', or the new, changed `id`
    IO.puts child.parent.id # returns '5', or the old id
                            # child.parent is stale
# ...
```

What is the proper way to retrieve the newly associated parent record after updating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in way to do this in Ecto for now. You also have the issue that you can't use preload, as the association has already been preloaded.

One option is this:

```
%{child | parent: Repo.get!(Parent, child.parent_id)}
```

You can also choose to not call preload until after you call `Repo.update` which will prevent the association already being loaded.

Comment: With Ecto 2.0, you can now pass `force: true` to `Repo.preload` to force reloading of an already-loaded association. Source: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.0.0-rc.1/Ecto.Repo.html#c:preload/3

Comment: @JonathanPerret worth turning your comment into an answer? In modern versions of Ecto, this seems to be the idiomatic way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Force the preload. By default, Ecto won’t preload associations that are already loaded.

```
child
|> Child.changeset(params)
|> Repo.update!()
|> Repo.preload(:parent, force: true)
```

or without a bang update if you want to handle errors differently

```
child
|> Child.changeset(params)
|> Repo.update()
|> case do
  {:ok, child} -> {:ok, Repo.preload(child, :parent, force: true)}
  error -> error
end
```

In a more realistic example with error handling, it could look something like

```
with {:ok, child} <- get_child(child_id),
     {:ok, child} <- update_child(child, params) do
  # Do stuff
else
  {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} -> # Handle error
  {:error, reason} -> # Handle error
end

defp get_child(child_id) do
  case Repo.get(Child, child_id) do
    nil -> {:error, :not_found}
    child -> {:ok, child}
  end  
end

defp update_child(child, params) do
  updated_child = 
    child
    |> Child.changeset(params)
    |> Repo.update!()
    |> Repo.preload(:parent, force: true)
rescue
  error in Ecto.InvalidChangesetError -> {:error, error.changeset}
  error in RuntimeError -> {:error, error.message}
end
```